# PHP SOAP xml response not decode xml tags

Tags: php, xml, soap, encoding

SOAP server try to return corrupted xml, and I'm getting error: `looks like we got no XML document`

Corrupted xml looks like:

```
<loyaltyReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;
```

Code is:

```
ob_start();
$response = $this->soap->handle();
echo $response;

$out = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo $out;

exit;
```

I try add `echo html_entity_decode($response);` but still not work, where can be problem with encoding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [SoapServer::handle](http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.handle.php) returns no response. Construction like

```
$response = $this->soap->handle();
echo $response;
```

does not make much sense to me.

Secondly, patching corrupted request is a slippery slope. Don't encourage clients to send you junk and expect sensible response. You take a lot of responsibility to make weak assumptions which leads to unpredictable behaviour and hidden bugs in your server implementation.

The SOAP server should accept [valid SOAP Envelope](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp) and reject everything else.